# SQLite Update "Cannot update List1: it has no PK"

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, datetime, windows-phone-8

I'm having an issue when trying to update a value on my database and can't really find much if any help through Google.

I want to set a column called IsOpen (bool but because of SQLite I'm using integer) to 0 (false) if the EndDate for this entry is today (now). When I run my UPDATE query I get the following exception; "Cannot update List1: it has no PK".

I don't understand this because I've checked my Model class and I clearly have a PK set;

```
    [SQLite.AutoIncrement, SQLite.PrimaryKey]
    public int GoalID
    {
        get { return _goalID; }
        set
        {
            if (_goalID != value)
                _goalID = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("GoalID");
        }
    }
```

I'm attempting to update this way;

```
    string sql = @"UPDATE GoalsTrackerModel 
                   SET IsOpen = '0' 
                   WHERE EndDate = datetime('now')"; // I've also tried date('now')
    _dbHelper.Update<GoalsTrackerModel>(sql);
```

My Update<> looks like;

```
    public void Update<T>(string stmt) where T : new()
    {
        using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.ConnectionString))
        {
            var result = conn.Query<T>(stmt);

            if (result != null)
            {
                conn.RunInTransaction(() =>
                    {
                        conn.Update(result);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
```

But like I said, I keep getting "Cannot update List1: it has no PK". What's throwing me off as well is if I change the WHERE to something like; WHERE IsOpen = '1' then it'll update all the values that have 1 to 0, but it'll still give me the "Cannot update List1: it has no PK" message.

Maybe my WHERE is wrong when checking if the EndDate = now? I'm implementing all this as soon as the page is opened. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"[SQLite.AutoIncrement, SQLite.PrimaryKey]" is C# code, not SQL code.  Just because you've defined in C# what your primary key is, doesn't mean the SQLite table is really defined that way.  You'll need to look at the table itself as it is defined within SQLite to fix that.

Comment: I've set my SQLite database incl. PK exactly how every tutorial shows, I can't see any other way of doing it. It seems to update regardless of that exception when I do the other WHERE clause, but just not the one involving the date. I was hoping someone could maybe tell me if I'm wrong in how I'm doing the WHERE EndDate = datetime('now').

Comment: Can you show us the CREATE statement that created your SQLite table (GoalsTrackerModel)?

Comment: In App.xml.cs constructor; using(var conn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)) { conn.CreateTable<GoalsTrackerModel>(); } I'm posting from my phone right now so can't really indent, etc.

Comment: Fixed my problem. My Update method was completely wrong and was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My Update method was causing the problem. Changed it and started using SQLiteCommand and ExecuteNonQuery instead of the SQLiteConnection's Update().

In case it helps anyone in the future, here's my new update method;

```
public void Update<T>(string stmt, string table) where T : new()
{
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.ConnectionString))
    {
        var result = conn.Query<T>("SELECT * FROM " + table);

        if (result != null)
        {
            conn.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {
                    SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand(stmt);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Update method runs a SELECT?